# Xgboost pairwise ranking for 1 or 0 target variable

Tags: python, xgboost, ranking, pairwise

I have a dataset of webpage searches:

```
SearchId    WebpageId      Clicked
A           1              1
A           4              0
A           6              0

B           1              0
B           3              0
B           4              0
B           10             1

C           1              0
C           3              0
C           5              0
C           6              1
C           7              0
C           8              0
C           9              0

...
```

For each search I know the webpages shown (but not the order of how they were shown) and I know if the link to the webpage was clicked or not. Only one webpage per search can be clicked.

Is it possible to use xgboost pairwise ranking in this case? How?

If not, what else could I use?

Comment: Got to understand a bit better the XGBoost ranking mechanism and it cannot be used without ranking labels in the train set. Still interested in some alternative approach...

Answer (score 0):

The [pairwise approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#Pairwise_approach) "can tell which document is better in a given pair of documents": the dataset that you posted seems to me more suitable for the pointwise approach which basically is a regression problem.

However, given your constrained that just a page is clicked, I think that you can transform your dataset in

```
SearchId    WebpageId_1   WebpageId_2     Labels^*
  A           1              4             GOOD
  A           4              6             SAME
  A           6              1             NOT_GOOD
 ...
 
 *^labels are according to the event of click on the first WebpageId.
```

run the algorithm (e.g. XGBoost with rank:pairwise) and finally sort the result in a list from which you can choose the top Webpage for each SearchID (the sorting task can be time-consuming and hard to do accurately).
For a different approach, you can have a look at [this post](https://dec0de.me/2014/10/learning-to-rank-1) about pairwise ranking and Neural Networks